# Radical equation $x- 5\sqrt{x} + 4 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve: Radical equation $x- 5\sqrt{x} + 4 = 0$

I think I understand what I had did wrong. Instead of squaring a product of a number I was squaring the equation.

Comment: I tried to TeXify your calculations, but it is somewhat difficult to do so, because I couldn't quite figure out your intention, and adding my own guesses would alter the contents, because the steps that apparently confuse you would then look different.

Comment: You would do better to put $y^2=x$ and solve the resulting quadratic for $y$. Your question as asked is somewhat confusing. I tried to edit it, but lost track of what you were trying to do.

Comment: For example, when you compute the $(-5\sqrt x)^2$, you seem to get some extra terms in there. Do you know that $-5\sqrt x$ is the **product** of $-5$ and $\sqrt x$? And when you square the product of two numbers, it goes as follows: $$(ab)^2=a^2b^2.$$ In your calculation it looks like you want to include the term $2ab$. But that only appears, when you square the **sum** $a+b$.

Comment: Okay I thought it was (a+b)^2 *= (a^2 + 2ab + b^2). Thank you soooo much. I did not realize that.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The easiest method of solution is to let $x=y^2$, so you have
$$
y^2 - 5y + 4 = 0
$$
Solve for $y$, then substitute into $x=y^2$ to get your final answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$x-5\sqrt{x}+4=0$$
$$x+4=5\sqrt{x}$$
$$x^2+16+8x=25x$$
$$x^2-17x+16=0$$
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{17\pm\sqrt{17^2-16\cdot 4}}{2}$$
$$x_1=16\qquad;\qquad x_2=1$$

Comment: Wow! You're good.Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ 0 = \sqrt{x}^2 - 5 \sqrt{x} + 4 = (\sqrt{x}-4)(\sqrt{x}-1)\,\Rightarrow\,\sqrt{x} = \,\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Set $y^2=x$ so that the equation becomes $y^2-5y+4=0$.

This has solutions $y=1, y=4$ by any standard method.

So $x=y^2=1 \text{ or } 16$.